# Issues with reading from a file using overloaded input

Tags: c++, ifstream

So I'm having issues reading from a file with an overloaded input operator ">>"

This is my code for int main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testHeader.h"
#include <vector>
#include "testHeader2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("inputfile.txt");
    vector<testHeader2> c;
    c.resize(5);
    inFile >> c[0];
    cout << c[0];
    cout << endl;
    c[0].setHeader2("a", 1,2,3,4,5,6);
    cout << c[0];
    return 0;
}
```

and this is my header file test:

```
#ifndef TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
#define TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "testHeader2.h"
class testHeader2
{
    private:
        std::string str;
        double d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6;
    public:
        void setHeader2(std::string mystr, double g, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)
        {
            str = mystr;
            d1 = g;
            d2 = b;
            d3 = c;
            d4 = d;
            d5 = e;
            d6 = f;

        }
        friend std::ifstream& operator>> (std::ifstream& input, testHeader2& a)
        {
        input >> a.str
        >> a.d1
        >> a.d2
        >> a.d3
        >> a.d4
        >> a.d5
        >> a.d6;
        return input;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output, const testHeader2 &a)
        {
        output << a.str << std::right << std::setprecision(2)
        << a.d1 << a.d2 <<
        a.d3 << a.d4 <<
        a.d5 << a.d6;
        return output;
        }

};

#endif // TESTHEADER2_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is a line from the .txt

AAAA 120 140 150 160 170 10000

My output overload seems to work, tested with the setHeader2 function.

What am I doing wrong? It seems to go off the rails after the first string, as it thereafter puts random values into the double values. It successfully reads the string, and then fails to read the doubles. Can anyone explain what's going wrong here? Are the spaces somehow messing things up? They never have in the past...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't given us enough of your code to reproduce the problem; the bug may well be in the code you haven't shown us, and in any case examining the code you *have* shown us is a lot of work because we can't run it without filling in the missing pieces. And whether you ask for help or not, you must learn to *simplify*. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you write code, start with something small and simple that works, then build up; write code that reads *one* `StockInfo` before you attempt to read a sequence of them.

Comment: I think  the main question looks more in line with what is expected around here. Hopefully that helps, and thanks for the advice!

Comment: The code you have now posted is enough to run-- and it seems to work. There may be some undefined behavior in there somewhere; I doubt this code is minimal.